Nginx static config
My static config is like below.
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     emad.ir;

        location /  {
        root    /Apps/first;
        index   index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html  {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

}

when i enter the IP address in the browser,It works fine but when i enter server name,It doesn't resolve that.anyone has a suggestion about this?

This is probably nothing to do with the nginx config. It'll be a DNS misconfiguration. Have you tried ping emad.ir and verified it gives the IP you expect?

emad.ir is my made up server_name.actually i run my nginx on my local server.I have ping to the Ip and it does n't understand ping for emad.ir.@Timmmm

Well if you just made it up then your DNS server doesn't know about it. Probably worth looking up how DNS works at least vaguely.

You need to actually buy emad.ir before you have the right to redirect that domain to your server.
